# How to keep CR when reading file into string?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I use code below to read file into string. The file is a CSV file on windows. Lines are ended by '\r\n'.

```
std::ifstream stream(fileName);
auto rawText = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

I notice that the '**\r\n**' is translated into '**\n**'.

Why this happens? How to keep '**\r\n**'?

Comment: Open the file in *binary* mode.

Comment: A c++ question have been marked as duplicate of a c question?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude why this happens? Is there an explanation?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad While this does seem odd at first, I can't find a better duplicate than what Sam did so unless you have a better suggestion I guess that's the best we have...

Comment: @Borgleader I think, instead of marking it a duplicate of some other language question, one should consider answering it, and could mention this link while answering.

Comment: @user1633272 in binary mode, it treats the files as just a stream of bytes, and reads from there. But without binary mode, it treats the file as text, so does some conversions.